# Can't access a property of a variable of multiple types

Tags: typescript

I have created a type that can be of some other type or some interface, so I can use that in a function.

```
type Value = string | number
interface IUser { name: string, id: string }
export type IGlobalUser = Value | IUser;
```

Now, when I want a function to get a parameter of type `IGlobalUser`, i would expect to be able to access props of the interface `IUser`. Like this:

```
foo(user: IrGlobalUser) { alert(user.name) }
```

However, TypeScript says:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | number | IUser'.   
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I want the function to be able to accept both `Value` and `IUser` and to use it, any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: Well what _should_ be alerted (or otherwise happen) if the value is a string or a number rather than an IUser? We can't tell you that. The compiler's telling you the right thing - the value passed might not have a name property.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i dont know, one time it can be string or value and another time and it can be IUser. if its IUser i want to access its props

Comment: So think about it and figure it out, we can't tell you what behaviour you want. Write code that checks that. Ensure that it _is_ a user object before treating it like one. Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html. But it's unclear why you expected any different outcome from what you wrote - you said it could be one of three cases, but only dealt with one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```typescript
type Value = string | number
interface IUser { name: string, id: string }
export type IGlobalUser = Value | IUser;

function isUser(checkObj: IGlobalUser): checkObj is IUser {
  const optionalUser = checkObj as IUser;
  // need to be sufficient to identify your case
  return isObject(optionalUser) &&
    optionalUser.id !== undefined &&
    optionalUser.name !== undefined;
}

function foo(user: IGlobalUser) {

  if (isUser(user)) {
    alert(user.name);
  }
} 

function isObject(obj: any) {
  return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';
}
```

The `isUser` function will get a type of `IGlobalUser`, and determines if it's an `IUser`. This will allow you to check at runtime what kind of type it is.

This translates to regular javascript, but typescript knows that this function determines the type.
When you use the user defined guard function, typescript will know which type it is

In VS Code:

- the first type is `IGlobalUser` as expected

  [image]
- the second type is `IUser` as expected

  [image]

When compiled to JavaScript, the `isUser` function and if statement will obviously be there. But you probably want a check like that somewhere in your code anyway. Writing it using a [Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) will do the necessary check at runtime, but will also make TypeScript aware of the two different scenarios and give you feedback accordingly.

Comment: The screenshots appear unrelated to the code you've written, `isMultiResponse`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right. fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

The function **accepts** both `Value` and `IUser`. TypeScript is warning you that you cannot know if the type of `user` is `string` or `number` or `IUser` and in the first two cases `user` does not have the property `name`.

Use a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) to tell the cases apart and the compiler won't complain any more:

```js
type Value = string | number
interface IUser { name: string, id: string }
type IGlobalUser = Value | IUser;

function foo(user: IGlobalUser) { 
    if (typeof user === 'object') {
        console.log(`IUser: ${user.name}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`string or number: ${user}`);
    }
} 

foo({ name: 'John Doe', id: '42'});
foo('Jane Doe');
foo(43);
```

Check it [online](https://tsplay.dev/N7KRGN).

Answer (score -1):

JS solution => better for runtime also

```
foo(user: IrGlobalUser) {
  alert((typeof user === 'object') && user.name)
}
```

TS solution => Work only at compile time

```
foo(user: IrGlobalUser) {
  alert((user as IUser).name)
}
```